# Cross account AWS event bridge

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codepipeline, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to set up cross account event bridge from Account A to Account B to trigger codepipeline which is in ACCOUNT B.
ACCOUNT A - I have set up S3 ,AWS EVENT BUS to send the event when the object is added to s3 to ACCOUNT B.
ACCOUNT B - I have set up AWS EVENT BUS to receive the event from ACCOUNT A and codepipeline as target to trigger.

I have an issue with sending the event from ACCOUNT A to ACCOUNT B using event bus and also i want to setup policy and permission in ACCOUNT B to receive event from ACCOUNT A and trigger codepipeline.

How can this be achieved?

I'm following the script :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEvents-CrossAccountEventDelivery.html

Comment: Please provide details about the error that you are encountering.

Answer (score 5):

To configure cross-account event bridge communication following needs to be done. I am providing sample event and filters, you can replace the event and filters as per requirment. Focus on to resolve inter account connectivity.

[image]

**Steps to be performed on Account B: Receiver account**

1. Create an event bus named event-bus-b. Put the resource-based policy as shown below.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "WebStoreCrossAccountPublish",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-A>:root"
    },
    "Action": "events:PutEvents",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:events:<your-region>:<Account-B>:event-bus/event-bus-b"
  }]
}
```

**Steps to be performed on Account A: Sender account**

1. Create an event bus event-bus-a in account A.
2. Create a rule eb-rule-a in account A with the following details:

Event pattern:

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "uoe"
  ],
  "source": [
    "somesource"
  ]
}
```

Also, test the pattern using the test event.

Test Event:

```
  {
  "version": "0",
  "id": "55fghj-89a9-a0b3-1ccb-79c25c7d6cd2",
  "detail-type": "uoe",
  "source": "somesource",
  "account": "<ACCOUNT_ID>",
  "time": "2020-04-24T13:53:21Z",
  "region": "<YOUR_REGION>",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
   "userOrg" : "OrgName" 
  }
}
```

3. Select the event bus event-bus-a in the drop-down.
4. Select the target "Event bus in different account or Region"
5. Put the ARN of the event bus which you have created in Account B.

```
arn:aws:events:<your-region>:<Account-B>:event-bus/event-bus-b
```

6. Also check on the check box "Create a new role for this specific resource". This will create a role in account A which enables the users in account A to publish on account b event bus. The below policy is auto-created and you don't need to do anything.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "events:PutEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                arn:aws:events:<your-region>:<Account-B>:event-bus/event-bus-b
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

7. Click on create and create the rule.
8. Now click on the event bus event-bus-a and click on Send events button.
9. Provide details and click on send.

[image]

Sample event:

```
  {
  "version": "0",
  "id": "55fghj-89a9-a0b3-1ccb-79c25c7d6cd2",
  "detail-type": "uoe",
  "source": "somesource",
  "account": "<ACCOUNT_ID>",
  "time": "2020-04-24T13:53:21Z",
  "region": "<YOUR_REGION>",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
   "userOrg" : "OrgName" 
  }
}
```

10. Event will propagate to the event bus defined in account B. You can validate that by replicating the rule which we have created in account A in account B and just attach a lambda as a target to that rule and print the event on logs.